# How can I test in REPL whether two instances of the same class have the same attributes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I am trying to learn a new function or library, I like to see if I can run some simple example code in a REPL environment, like a Jupyter notebook, to test my understanding.

For this example, I want to see if I understand [part of the documentation](http://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trait_types.html#traitlets.List) for the `traitlets` module correctly. Specifically, I would like to be able to run in a Jupyter notebook something like:

```
from traitlets import List, Unicode
test1 = List(Unicode())
test2 = List(trait=Unicode())
test1 == test2
```

and have the result be "meaningful". The above runs right now, and returns `False`, but I am not sure that the result is actually "meaningful", because it seems like this is only because these two objects are pointing to different addresses in memory, not because they are actually `List`'s with different values. For example, one would see in the REPL something like:

```
 test1
 <traitlets.traitlets.List at 0x111a04748>
```

and

```
test2
<traitlets.traitlets.List at 0x111a046a0>
```

Is there a way to "de-traitletize" `test1` and `test2` so I can see whether or not they are "functionally/behaviorally" different (i.e. their attribute values are different), as opposed to just being two different instances of the same class pointing to two different places in memory?

I think this question might apply more generally to how to test "behavioral equality" of two instances of any class in Python. But in case there is something specific to the `traitlets` module which allows this question to be answered in this special case, but not more generally, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid question which has a stupid answer. The whole point of `traitlets` is that, to the "external observer", attributes which are some type of traitlet appear to be "normal". In other words, they are only meant to be observed *"externally"*, i.e. through a layer of indirection provided by a class definition, but are not meant to be inspected "directly".

Here is an MWE of what I mean:

```
import traitlets

class Fruits(traitlets.HasTraits):
    test_list = traitlets.List(trait=traitlets.Unicode(), default_value=['apple', 'orange'])

    def choose_fruit(self):
        fruit = self.test_list[0]
        return fruit

salad = Fruits()

salad.test_list()
```

`['apple', 'orange']`

```
salad.choose_fruit()
```

`'apple'`

```
for fruit in salad.test_list:
    print(fruit)
```

`apple`
`orange`

But if one starts by doing (as I originally did with the REPL in Juptyer notebook):

```
import traitlets
test_list = traitlets.List(trait=traitlets.Unicode(), default_value=['apple', 'orange'])
```

and tries to do things like:

`test_list[0]`

or

```
for fruit in test_list:
    print(fruit)
```

then one gets errors about how `'List'` objects don't support indexing or aren't iterable.

What I am trying to say is that if one wants to do silly little tests like this with `traitlets` on the REPL (e.g. in Jupyter Notebook), then one will first need to introduce a layer of indirection by defining a class first for which these traitlets are attributes (they can't be inspected directly).

Using the same MWE as in the question, one would have to do something like:

```
import traitlets

class Test1(traitlets.HasTraits):
     list = traitlets.List(traitlets.Unicode())

class Test2(traitlets.HasTraits):
     list = traitlets.List(trait=traitlets.Unicode())

test1 = Test1()
test2 = Test2()

test1.list == test2.list
```